# socket.io + ssl - Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, access-control

I build my project with socket.io v1.2.1 , which running well on http connections.

But when I change my website into ssl connection, errors coming.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
https://pusher.mydomain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1417509725164-0. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://other.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

"puhser.mydomain.com" is the server to provide io service, and "other.mydomain.com" running as a client of pusher.

Here is the code of IO Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var key = fs.readFileSync('./server.key').toString();
var cert = fs.readFileSync('./server.crt').toString();
var https_options = {
   key: key,
   cert: cert
};
http.createServer(https_options, app).listen(8080, function() {
   console.log('Listening 8080');
});
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log(socket.id);
    //...
});
//...
```

And, the client connect to the server like this:

```
var io = io.connect('https://pusher.mydomain.com:8080');
iosocket.on('connect',function(){
   //...
});
```

Then, the error comes.

I have tried many ways, but didn't help. God bless me!

@jfriend00 : Thank u. The domain/port of the websites are different.
I have tried this:
`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://other.mydomain.com");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});`

Then the error disappear,but IO connection can not be build, and I get 404 from the IO server.

Answer:

The ssl connections on socket.io has not been build in the right way.
I solve this question with:

```
//...
var https = require('https').createServer(https_options,app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(https);
// io connection code ...

https.listen(8080);
//...
```

Everything works well.

Comment: Are the domain/port of your web page the same as the domain/port of your webSocket connection?  If not, you may have to set some options on the server side so socket.io will accept different origins.  The simplest way to guarantee the same origin is to have the client code just be `var socket = io();` with no URL as that will default to the same origin.

Comment: FYI, multiline code is unreadable in comments.  Please use the edit link to add it to your original question, properly format it and then post a comment referring to it.